# Advice untangling SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2014 install

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have heard other developers (i.e., not db administrators) complain over the years about the complexity of getting SQL Server installed and configured properly.  I installed SQL Server 2014 about six months ago for a project that I'm no longer working on.  I tried installing 2008 R2 with a named instance for a new project but something went wrong and I now have an inaccessible instance.  My instinct is to remove everything and to just start fresh.  Is this the right instinct?

If it is the right instinct, any advice on how to fully, fully, fully uninstall all instances of SQL Server?  Seems every time I try to do so, there are some bits and pieces left behind and that gets me wondering if those leftover bits are causing trouble for subsequent re-installs.

If this is not the right instinct, please set me straight.  I'm hoping that all of the answers will not be "db administrators are paid to be good at this so go find one."  Of course, this is probably the best and most accurate response; but I would also like to solve my problem so if this is your response then I would be grateful if you could point me to a reliable, on-demand SQL Server admin service that I can consult to get this right -- I'm happy to pay for some high quality and efficient help.

Thanks for any advice.

Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that SQL Server 2008 R2 isn't supported on Windows 10: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2681562

So I uninstalled everything related to 2008 (which required a couple of reboots and further uninstall attempts) and then uninstalled everything I could find for 2014... and then I reinstalled 2014 from scratch... and I'm golden.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having problems accessing the server it's a good instinct to remove the name instance and install a new one. The reason you could not access the name instance could be compatibility problem b/n sql2014 and SQL 2008R2 or configuration problem. why do you really want to install SQL 2014 instead of sql2008? my be it's better to install SQL 2014 name instance.
please  look at this link to remove the name instance SQL 2008.
http://thoughtsonopsmgr.blogspot.com/2012/10/how-to-remove-sql-server-instance-from.html

Comment: I would also suggest to install them in "version increasing" order, to avoid any problems with shared libraries/dependencies. (I currently have SQL 2008 R2 Dev and SQL 2014 Express installed on my dev machine, both work fine)